# Are how-to's on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, answers

There are users who ask for an alternative to a software because it is missing some features they need. The problem is that the software they are using currently has that features but they are not aware of them.

This is an example: [AutoIt IDE with customizable code editor font](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/autoit-ide-with-customizable-code-editor-font). The SciTE editor used by AutoIt by default has options to customize editor font. The answer to this question is not a software recommendation, it is more a how-to change the font in SciTE.

**Do this kind of answers fit to Software Recommendations' format? Are they on-topic?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A question asking how to accomplish a task with some specific software, as opposed to looking for some software to accomplish that task, would be off-topic. Such questions would typically be on-topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for end-user software and for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for programming questions.

It may happen, sometimes, that the asker already has the software that they need but don't know it, as in your [SciTE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/autoit-ide-with-customizable-code-editor-font) example. If that's the case, then so be it. “You don't need any third-party software for this task” is a valid, if rare, answer here.

Comment: You beat me to it, Gilles (I could not post as the site was just gone read-only). In cases like these, we can simply recommend the software the user already has, pointing out how it matches his requirements etc., as with any other question – and that would be perfectly fine and valid.