# Are "no code" requests for tools in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

If someone asks for a no coding - ready to use tool recommendations, would it be acceptable?

Assuming that enough details are provided in such question.

Comment: Related: [Are how-to's on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/185)

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the example, as it would stir the discussion into one particular area.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, asking for tools that does not require coding is perfectly fine.

Actually, most of the answers on this site suggest tools that does not require coding.

By the way, asking for **tools** is fine, but a simple "how to…" is not, as detailed in [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](/q/336/185)

Answer (score 2):

Why should it not be aceptable. Not everybody is a programmer here and even I as a programmer see for example python solutions as completly useles for me. And it should be kept in mind that majority of people have no programming experiences at all.